# No check valve on valve cover

Tags: pcv-valve

On a 2004 Neon RT 2.0 SOHC we had an issue with one of the rockers. When we took the valve cover off to replace the rocker, we noticed that there was no baffle in the valve cover. There were large peices of tin sitting against the outer walls of the head. It was obvious the baffle had been destroyed some how.

One of the problems we're having is that there is a lot of oil coming from the valve cover into the air box. I'm not sure if this line is supposed to be a breather or a PCV. There is also what I assume to be the EGR which goes from the side of the valve cover down into the intake.

About 2 weeks ago we got another valve cover with a baffle. There is still oil getting into the air box even with the baffle. Should either/both of these these outlets be a check valve?

The air box has a built in holder for a sponge that collects the oil coming from the back of the valve cover.

Any ideas? Why, with the baffle, is there oil still going into the air box?

Comment: Did you clean out the piping between the breather and the airbox? Also, do you see oil fumes if you remove the oil filler cap when the engine is running?

Comment: pipe was clean, no I dont see any fumes.

Comment: The EGR is "exhaust gas recirculation".  It connects the exhaust and intake, usually through a valve which controls the amount of recirculation.  A properly-functioning EGR system helps heat the engine up faster and also improves combustion efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the oil return passages are plugged, then at high rpm or after sustained operation you may be building up lots of oil in the head which is then finding it's way out into the airbox.

Since you did have some parts come apart inside the top end, maybe some of the baffle ended up in the return passages and is preventing sufficient oil drainback.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Went ahead and dumped that car for an 05 SRT-4. No more problems.